# Wordpress get_the_excerpt instead of $post->post_excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to replace `$post->post_content` in the function below with `get_the_excerpt` that simply deducts an excerpt from `the_content` on the fly .

Original function:

```
function getExcerpt($post) {
    $summary = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    return apply_filters("mc-message", $summary);
}
```

I could have replaced `$post->post_content` with `$post->post_excerpt` but that would return nothing as there is no hard-corded excerpt entered in the Wordpress editor's excerpt meta box. Read that `get_the_excerpt` creates a summary out of the post content. But it didn't pass any value

```
function getExcerpt($post) {
    $deducted_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
    $summary = apply_filters('the_content', $deducted_excerpt);
    return apply_filters("mc-message", $summary);
}
```

Comment: get_the_excerpt fetched value from the excerpt box in post. if you want that value you have to enter excerpt in the post.

Comment: Minor code-style recommendation; in your filter, use underscore instead of hyphen: instead of `mc-message`, I'd recommend `mc_message` - In an ideal world, the names of your filters match the your filter _function names_ also, and a PHP function (or variable name) may not have a hyphen in them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. `get_the_excerpt` generates word-counted trimmed-down version of the full post content, when there is no user-supplied excerpt.
But here, you are not using `get_the_excerpt` inside the loop. So, you will need to pass a post object or post ID as parameter to fetch the excerpt.

From codex:

> If this function is used outside The Loop and the post doesn't have a custom excerpt, this function will use `wp_trim_excerpt()` to generate an excerpt. That function uses `get_the_content()`, which must be used with The Loop and will cause problems if `get_the_excerpt()` is being used outside The Loop. In order to avoid the issues, use `setup_postdata()` prior to calling `get_the_excerpt()` to set up the global `$post` object.

Your code should be:

```
function getExcerpt($post) {
    $deducted_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($post);//<==== see here. $post object is passed as parameter.
    $summary = apply_filters('the_content', $deducted_excerpt);
    return apply_filters("mc-message", $summary);
}
```

[More details on `get_the_excerpt()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/)

Comment: I initially had it defined withe the post id :

    $deducted_excerpt = get_the_excerpt($postID);

Answer (score 0):

I had initially passed the post id to it and still didn't return the truncated content excerpt I was hoping for.
Since the Codex suggests using the `seup_postdata`, I preceded my function with that.
And solved the issue:

```
function getExcerpt($post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $deducted_excerpt = custom_excerpt($post);
    $summary = apply_filters('the_content', $deducted_excerpt);
    return apply_filters("mc-message", $summary);
}
```